# Java Itext7 pdf font encoding - Polish characters not visible

Tags: java, pdf, character-encoding, itext, itext7

I am using the newest Itext7 version of the library for generating PDF's. I've stumbled upon this problem with fonts, basically some of the characters are missing depending on which encoding I'd choose. But there seems to be no encoding supporting Polish characters.

Here is the code I use to create the fonts:

```
public static final String FONT_BOLD = "src/main/resources/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf";
public static final String FONT_EXTRA_BOLD = "src/main/resources/fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf";
public static final String FONT_SEMI_BOLD = "src/main/resources/fonts/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf";

PdfFont boldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT_BOLD, PdfEncodings.CP1250);
PdfFont extraBoldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT_EXTRA_BOLD, PdfEncodings.CP1250);
PdfFont semiBoldFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT_SEMI_BOLD, PdfEncodings.CP1250);
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

But the above text should say "PODSUMOWANIE JADŁOSPISU".

I tried different encodings - UTF8, Unicode-H, Unicode-BIG, the best one is WINANSI (Cp1252) so far, but it also doesn't show Polish characters and some other characters are missing too:

[image]

"adospisu" - should be "Jadłospisu"

"niadanie" - should be "Śniadanie"

"Dzie" - should be "Dzień"

Please if you have any idea how to fix this let me know.

Comment: That btw is the wrong path to the fonts. Applications are not interested in your Maven build environment or the file system. Those fonts should be loaded as resources with a resource path like `"/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf";`

Comment: you're right, thanks

Comment: Just tried it with that font and Polish is fine for me

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: No. I didn't specify an encoding though. What is `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` for you?

Comment: The encoding is “Cp1252”

Comment: Hang on! Just tried  "PODSUMOWANIE JADŁOSPISU". and I see it's missing the  "Ł". It might lack the glyph for U+0141

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244135/discussion-between-g00se-and-piotr-chabros).